# template parsing URL in java

Tags: java, query-string, httpclient, string-parsing, jodd

I have a application that receive a message from SMPP server and forward the received message to users web services. all users have a URL in database like this:

```
http://www.example.com/get.php?from=${originator}&to=${destination}&data=${content}
http://www.example.com/submit?origin=${originator}&dst=${destination}&cnt=${content}
```

All of them have `${originator}`,`${destination}`,`${content}` in their pattern. they may have other parameters in their URL or not. I use Jodd `StringTemplateParser` to replace above arguments after getting user URL from database:

```
private StringTemplateParser stp = new StringTemplateParser();
private final Map<String, String> args = new HashMap<>();

args.put("originator", msg.getOriginator());
args.put("destination", msg.getDestination());
args.put("content", msg.getContent());

String result = stp.parse(deliveryUrl, new MacroResolver() {
    @Override
    public String resolve(String macroName) {
        return args.get(macroName);
    }
});
```

Then I use apache http client to call user URL:

```
URL url = new URL(result);
int port = url.getPort();
uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), null, url.getHost(), port == -1 ? 80 : port, url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = null;
try {
    request = new HttpGet(uri);
    client.execute(request)
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (request != null) {
        request.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

I tried to do some encoding because user may send any text containing characters like `%$&`. The problem is when `content` contains something like `hello&x=2&c=3243` user only gets `hello`. `URI` class treats that as regular `GET` query parameter. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the parameter values when you are building your new URI.

You can encode the parameters using [URLEncoder.encode(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29).

So, in your `MacroResolver`, just return `URLEncoder.encode(map.get(macroName))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you need to use HTTP default content char-set something like this for your code

request = new HttpGet(url+"?"+URLEncodedUtils.format(namevaluepair,
                                    HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET));